# FAQ: permissible topics for questions

Tags: support, on-topic

Where can I find a description of German Language SE's policy on admissible question types and topics, either as a stand-alone page, or as an FAQ somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from the help center gives you an overview of the most important cases and is intended to answer exactly this question for first-time users.
- Apart from this, you should find every previous discussion on on-topicness should be tagged [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) here on Meta (and many of them are also linked on the above help-center page). If you find some Meta question that is not tagged [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) but should be, please flag it or mention it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/deutschsprachiger-raum).